# LESSCSS: Retrieve variables values with JQuery

Tags: less

I know that with

```
less.modifyVars({'@parameter' : <value from form field>});
```

I could change on-the-fly value of a LESS variable but I would like to do the opposite task: retrieve current value of a LESS variable/parameter. I thought about a syntax such as:

```
less.getVarsValues('@parameter');
```

but I did not find nothing like that. Is there a way (with LESS method or jQuery) to get current value?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This script loads a LESS stylesheet (`stylesheets/variables.less`) from the same server your pages are served and prints the variables in a list (`<ol id='varlist'></ol>`):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var parser = new(less.Parser);
    $.get("stylesheets/variables.less", function( data ) {
        parser.parse(data, function (e, tree) {
            var variables = tree.variables();
            for (i in variables) {
                var name = variables[i].name;
                var value = variables[i].value;
                $("#varlist").append("<li>"+name + ":" + value+"</li>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know where the `variables` object is documented so I don't know if it is official. I discovered it through introspection of the `tree` object (experimenting with [this example](http://lesscss.org/#using-less-configuration)).

Comment: mhmmmm if I'm correctly understanding, with this script I can retrieve value that I dinamically set with JS, not default LESS params defined in a LESS file placed on server. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, I posted a simplified example. I will edit the answer and post a complete script, reading a LESS file in the server.

Comment: Ok, so it does not exist a specific method like "less.modifyVars" but always a "workaround" in jQuery?

Comment: Not really a workaround, since the objects do exist and are necessary. What I meant about not being official is that I didn't find it in the documentation. I used pure JavaScript above, but of course you can also use JQuery and make it simpler.

Comment: I replaced the pure JavaScript solution with a JQuery solution.